# Is there is a way to remove the purple frame on the selected button of Radio Button Group (Display as Pill Button)? Oracle Apex

Tags: css, radio-button, oracle-apex, radio-group

[image]

There is a purple frame on the button which is selected (When we clicked on it has purple outline) . Is there is any way to remove it?

I tried a lot of thing even with CSS but not working. What am I doing wrong?

`.your-radio-group-class input[type="radio"]:checked {`

`outline: none; /* Remove the outline (purple frame) */ }`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to remove the `box-shadow`:

```css
.your-radio-group-class input[type="radio"]:checked {  
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

Right-click on the element in the web-browser and select "Inspect" and, if enabled, that should bring up the developer console and show you the CSS properties of the element. You should then be able to see if the element has a box-shadow style (or inherits it from somewhere) and can toggle it on and off to see quickly whether that style is generating the purple border you are seeing. You can also check whether you have the correct CSS selector for the element when you inspect it (as the formatting may be on the label for the radio button and not on the radio button).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not working, I did the thing that you wrote it here. I wondered if I use wrong class, then I did for both button and the radio group one by one to tried it but non of them working

Comment: @Atalante "Its not working" is not a constructive statement as it does not tell us which bit was not working. Can you view the page in the browser? If so, can you inspect the element in the browser's developer console? If so, does it have a CSS box-shadow? Can you toggle the box-shadow off in the developer console? Does that remove the purple border? If so, is the element actually the `input` or is it a `label` for the input? Does the CSS selector for the element match the CSS selector you were trying to use? Etc....

Comment: When I said "it's not working" I thought I answered all this questions. Yes , I can view the page in browser. Yes, I can inspect the element. No, it doesn't have CSS box-shadow. I can't turn off the box-shadow because there is no. I found the solution when I use "input + label". I understand you're disappointed that your idea didn't work, but thank you for your effort, it's appreciated. It help me to understand where am I wrong.

Comment: @Atalante I was trying to help you but I cannot see your screen and did not know what you had tried and which bits had/had not worked. With more information you would have got a more refined/applicable solution. The main aim was to give you a technique where you could find the solution yourself; you've done that so there is no disappointment, instead the opposite - satisfaction, as you have resolved your issue.

Comment: Perfect than! Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

I found solution like this; I click whole radio button (not on label) then copy the selector path. I was thinking the selector path need to be long because I want to do changes when it "focus" but it turns out so easy.
It gave me this ; #P10_RADIOGROUPEXAMPLE

I added this to inline CSS;

```
#P10_RADIOGROUPEXAMPLE input[type="radio"]:focus + label {
outline: none !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
border: 2px solid transparent !important; // 'none' was not working so I made it transparent
```

}

I have another radio-group on same page and I did the same it gave me;
#P10_RADIOGROUPEXAMPLE2
I added this to inline CSS;

```
#P10_RADIOGROUPEXAMPLE2 input[type="radio"]:focus + label,
#P10_RADIOGROUPEXAMPLE2 label:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: 2px solid transparent !important;
}
```

And it solved! Turns out its so easy and I was blind I guess, mistakes can happen.
I will keep the question-answers for myself and for somebody who need it in future.